# iPhone simulator understands first "click" jQuery event, but not the second

Tags: jquery, ios, safari, touch

I'm finding this a bit confusing, if anyone else has run into this and could enlighten me...

I have one `click` event listener set up using jQuery which registers just fine, but the second doesn't, however, in the second, the `touchend` event does register.

`$(document).on("click", ".date-button", ...`

and the second similar event listener on a different element:

`$(document).on("click touchend", ".time.true", ...`

I have to use `touchend`, because the `click` doesn't register.
I would be happy to use both, `click touchend` but if I do that in the first listener, then the behaviour runs twice, (once for click and once again for touchend)!

### Update

I figured out that the problem was that I was "perhaps" delegating too many events on the `document`. When I delegated the second `click` listener to read something like `$("#times-popup").on("click", ".time.true", ...` it worked again.

I still think this is a bug somewhere, either in jQuery or iOS... more likely jQuery, or am I doing something I'm not supposed to?

Comment: I'm a little curious about this - can you provide some live code?  I'd like to try it on real iOS devices and the simulator and see if there's any difference.

Answer (score 1):

> On the iPhone, event delegation does not work for the click event. It works fine for mouseover and mouseout, fine for the touch events, but not for click.
>
> However... event delegation does work if the target of the event is a link or an input field.

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/click_event_del.html

So, one approach would be to change your `.date-button` element to type `a` or `input`. Alternatively, adding a little CSS to your page might also fix your bug:

```
.date-button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

See: http://jimmybyrum.com/tests/eventdelegation.html